# mysqli_stmt_execute not inserting values to database

Tags: php, android

```
<?php
$dbhost="00webhost.com";
$dbuser="a55826qwqw";
$dbpass="subseasdasd";
$dbname="asdasdas";
$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$name=$_POST["name"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
$mail=$_POST["mail"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO mandi(nAme,uSername,pHoneno,mAil,pAssword) VALUES($name,$username,$phone,$mail,$password)") or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

the values are taken from android  i.e name ,username and others.
but When i give strings instead of $name,$username etc it inserts .
please tell me where iam wrong.

the above same works fine for this statement

```
$statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO   mandi(nAme,uSername,pHoneno,mAil,pAssword) VALUES('me','user',123,'mailw','user')");
```

The android part to send data to server is

```
 ArrayList<NameValuePair>dataToSend=new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",user.name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone",user.phone+""));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail",user.mail));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));


       HttpParams httpParams=new BasicHttpParams();
       HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
      HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post=new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS+"Register.php");
        //Log.d("address",SERVER_ADDRESS+"Register.php");
        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: ok...please help me bro.im struct from 2 days

Comment: what is the form method: Post or Get ?

Comment: it is the POST method

Comment: On your $vars in your values.. do "'.$var.'"  `'` then `"` `.` Var name `.` `"` `'`

Comment: you also need to bind your param. Bind_param();

Comment: $statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO mandi(nAme,uSername,pHoneno,mAil,pAssword) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)") or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_bind_param($statement,"ssisss",$name,$username,$phone,$mail,$password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

Comment: Please read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php you dont have your structure setup right imo.

Comment: @LeviZoesch: how to modify the $vars as u told,im not getting exactly ,plz help me

Comment: Are you retrieving information from JSON, or ?

Comment: no im just using name value pair ,thank you now i can add user database. Its now corrected ..i left the binding part..

Comment: Awesome, glad I was able to help :)

Comment: @LeviZoesch: thanks a  lot ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet I wrote that I use for my basic bind_param functions.

```
    //  Assigned key            
$var = ??


                // Insert the new user into the database 
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO table (
column,...,...
     )
        VALUES (
        ?,..,..,)";

       $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

        // Insert the new user into the database
        if ($insert_stmt)
        {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ss',$var, $var);

            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
               echo 'error';
            }
        }
        }
```